# how to expand dojo tree expand using recursive function

Tags: dojo, tree

Hi I want to expand dojo(1.7) tree by programmatically ....

How to do nth node using recursive function
This code will expand node up to 3rd level but i need it should open automatically nth node

```
function expandAll(object) {
      object = object.slice(0,1);


nodes = tree.rootNode.getChildren();

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];
    if (node.isExpandable) {            
       if (node.getTreePath()[1].id == object[1]) {

            tree._expandNode(node);
            var childs = node.getChildren();

            for ( j = 0; j < childs.length; j++) {
                child = childs[j];
                if (child.getTreePath()[2].id == object[2]) {
                    tree._expandNode(child);
                    console.log("->" + child.getTreePath()[2].name[0]);
                    if (child.isExpandable) {
                        var subchilds = child.getChildren();
                        for ( k = 0; k < subchilds.length; k++) {
                            subchild = subchilds[k];
                            console.log("-> ->" + subchild.getTreePath()[3].name[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into using recursion so you're not limited to a certain number of levels.